# Win32 (C++) :- How to make a list item collapsible

Tags: c++, winapi, listitem, win32gui, collapsable

I have a listbox in which multiple list items are there. I want to implement something like if we click on the list item, it will collapse and show the summary of the clicked item:

[image]

I have been searching this on the web for quite sometime but haven't got any good solution. I am very new to Win32. Any suggestions on how to approach this like which control should I use. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Do you have code that isn't working? Then show your [MCVE]. Do you want code that works? We don't do that here. Do you want a direction to a tutorial or to code that works? We don't do that here, either.

Comment: @VipinNagar The question is specifically about `winapi`. The answer you provided is about html...

Comment: A [List Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775146.aspx) doesn't provide that feature, neither does a [List View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx). You'll either implement your own, or use a library, like MFC (see [CMFCPropertyGridCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983759.aspx) and similar). @VipinNagar: Trying to help is fine. However, if *trying* is all you have to offer, just don't.

Comment: It is possible to do with a standard ListBox. I have done it before. But it does take some extra work to pull off.

Comment: A ListView DOES support this since a while (Vista I think). Look out for "Groups" on Listviews.  LVM_ENABLEGROUPVIEW, LVM_INSERTGROUP. You need to enable visual controls (add ComnCtr 6.0 to your manifest - see here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775146.aspx) and [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx) controls do not natively support expanding/collapsing items, however it is possible to implement it in a ListBox with some extra work.

Give the ListBox the `LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` [list box style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149.aspx) to allow the list to contain items of different heights.  When a new item is added to the list, the ListBox will send a [`WM_MEASUREITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775925.aspx) message to its parent window asking for the item's initial height.  Return an appropriate height based on whether the item should be displayed as collapsed or expanded.

Once an item has been added to the list, you can send the ListBox a [`LB_SETITEMHEIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761348.aspx) message to assign a new height for that item based on whether it should now be displayed collapsed or expanded.  Then invalidate the ListBox to trigger a repaint of the items.

The `LBS_OWNERDRAW...` styles require you to manually draw each list item whenever the ListBox sends a [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923.aspx) message to its parent window.  You can draw the requested item on the provided `HDC` however you want, such as with the [`DrawText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498.aspx) function, configuring its parameters based on whether the item's text is currently being displayed as collapsed or expanded.  Also use the state information provided by the message itself to configure the `HDC`'s font and background/foreground colors as desired (particularly important when rendering items in the selected and focused states).

With that in place, all you have left to do is make your click handler determine the index of the item being clicked on (via [`GetMessagePos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx), [`ScreenToClient()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952.aspx), and [`LB_ITEMFROMPOINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761323.aspx)), and then assign it a new height based on its new expanded/collapsed state, and let the resulting repaint draw the new text accordingly.